# Делаю сайт на Django. Хочу на главную страницу вывести по одной картинке из каждой категории, есть более короткий способ сделать это?

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, django

```
class Index(View):

    def get(self, request):
        zooimg = ItemImage.objects.filter(category__category='zoo')
        portrait = ItemImage.objects.filter(category__category='portrait')
        bw_portraits = ItemImage.objects.filter(category__category='bw_portraits')
        landscape = ItemImage.objects.filter(category__category='landscape')
        flowers = ItemImage.objects.filter(category__category='flower')
        front = [zooimg.reverse()[0], portrait.reverse()[0], bw_portraits.reverse()[0], landscape.reverse()[0], flowers.reverse()[0]]

        return render(request, 'main/index.html', locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Max

ids = [i[1] for i in ItemImage.objects
                              .values_list('category__category')
                              .annotate(id=Max('id'))]
images = ItemImage.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'images': images})
```